# Using a regular expression to match filenames from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-re

I have a dictionary of filenames:

```
dic = {
    'this_file_name':'*this_file_name*.csv',
    'another': '*another*.csv'
    }
```

I have a path:

`file_path = glob.glob('path/to/files/*')`

I'm trying to implement some logic that looks in the folder and sees if any files match the values in the dictionary.

```
for files in file_path:
    if re.match(dic.values(), files):
        # do stuff with the files
```

I'm not sure how to implement this though.

Comment: Your dictionary values are globs, not regular expressions. Why not just use `glob.glob` again? Or just `glob.glob('/path/to/files/' + dict_value)`?

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: The unasked question in your post seems to be how to turn something like `*another*.csv` into a regular expression. I would suggest that you don't attempt that. I'd use `glob.glob` or `glob` + `fnmatch`.

Comment: Or maybe you're asking how to modify `dic`?

Comment: I have files that match the patterns in the dict values, I have several dicts with different key value pairs. I want to match files that match the patterns (dict values)

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary values are not valid regular expressions -- they are globs. Given that, you can just use `glob.glob` to match files (`method1`). Alternatively, you can use `glob.glob` to get a list of files in the directory and `fnmatch` to test each glob in your dictionary (`method2`). Finally, you can modify the values in `dic` to actually be regular expressions (`method3`).

```
search_dir = '.'

import glob

d1 = {
    'this_file_name': '*this_file_name*.csv',
    'another': '*another*.csv'
}

def method1():
    for k, v in d1.items():
        matches = glob.glob(search_dir + '/' + v)
        if matches:
            print(k, matches)


import fnmatch

def method2():
    names = glob.glob(search_dir + '/*')
    for k, v in d1.items():
        matches = fnmatch.filter(names, v)
        if matches:
            print(k, matches)

import re

d2 = {
    'this_file_name': 'this_file_name.*\.csv$',
    'another': 'another.*\.csv$'
}

def method3():
    names = glob.glob(search_dir + '/*')
    for k, v in d2.items():
        matches = [name for name in names if re.search(v, name)]
        if matches:
            print(k, matches)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    method1()
    method2()
    method3()
```